# Bash: Removing Multiple Files

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, files

Beginner here...

I have a fruit folder, named "apples," that has extra files I want to remove.

> Remove all files that begin with "red_dk" and "red_lt"
> Remove all files that end with ".gif"

If I do a single file, it works.

```
#!/bin/bash
rm "red_dk*"
```

If I do multiple, it does not

```
#!/bin/bash
rm "red_dk" "red_lt*" "*.gif"
```

Comment: Your first command `rm "red_dk*"` does not work... It deletes a file named exactly "red_dk*" and won't delete for example "red_dk_hello".

Answer (score 4):

The `*` character (as well as `?` and `[a-z]`-style character groups) match all files with all the other non–wildcard parts in their name name, and *expand the argument list* to include all those matching filenames.  This is called "glob file expansion".

You can preview it using `echo`.

eg:

```
$ echo red_dk* red_lt* *.gif
red_dk1 red_dk2 red_lt1 red_lt2 meme.gif answer.gif
$
```

To remove the files, replace `echo` with `rm`.  I tend to stack them, like `echo rm`.

If you somehow ended up with a literal `*` in your filename, then you could remove that file specifically by quoting it.  Quoting, single or double, avoids "glob file expansion".

```
$ echo "red_dk*"
red_dk*
$ rm "red_dk*"
rm: cannot remove 'red_dk*': No such file or directory
$
```